# Why are the outter tracks of a magnetic disks more stable?

Tags: computer-engineering

In our digital computers class, the professor mentioned that the outter tracks of a magnetic disk is more reliable because the outter bit are "bigger". Isn't the packing density of a magnetic disk uniform? If we compare this with a optical CD, the inner tracks are more reliable. Why is this the case?

Comment: Probably because of how it works.

Comment: Magnetic disks work in pair with an air layer (the larger radius create more velocity, so the air layer is denser the fartest to the center)

Comment: Hard drives run at constant speed. The outer sectors are the same angular size but are a longer path. CDs run at constant surface read speed. They run at high speed when the head is near the centre and slow down as it moves out. You can hear the disk spin up and down as it runs.